# How to understand "got a good bit of use out of them"

Tags: phrase-meaning, british-english, colloquial-language

> ‘Fred and George have invented Extendable Ears, see,’ said Ron. ‘They're really useful.’
>
> ‘Extendable—?’
>
> ‘Ears, yeah. Only we've had to stop using them lately because Mum
>   found out and went berserk. Fred and George had to hide them all to
>   stop Mum binning them. But we **got a good bit of use out of them** before
>   Mum realised what was going on.
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*</sub>

In my opinion, "got a good bit of use out of them" probably means *make good use of them* or *benefit from them*. But I'm not sure what it means exactly here. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are are suggesting that they managed to use them for an amount of time (or number of uses) that they found good. While not explicit here the usual implication would be that this would be measured against the effort or cost to acquire (or make) them.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct.

> He bought that old jalopy four years ago for very little money, and he's gotten four years of use out of it.

He has derived benefit from it.